# Serving a map completely offline?

Tags: javascript, json, offline, html5

What is the easiest way to deliver a map completely offline? E.g. like if I wanted to package it up and put it on a mobile device that is not in range of wifi.

How would one serve up map tiles w/o a tiling server?

Specifically looking for something javascript based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it would probably be easiest with MBTiles http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MBTiles. GeoPackage http://www.geopackage.org/ is rather similar, has more features but is not widely used yet. OpenStreetMap projects have good support for MBTiles. You can also consider vector tiles https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/.

Answer (score 0):

You put your tiles into a local directory and point your library to request them from there.

Comment: Which library though? Do you have an example or a recommended code library?